# How do I add a Loop to my code so it repeats 10 times and then provides a final score?

Tags: python

How do I add a loop to my code so it repeats 10 times and then provides a final score? Here is the code I've tried so far:

```
import random

randomNumber1 = random.randint ( 1,250 )
randomNumber2 = random.randint ( 1,250 )

def askQuestion():
    global randomNumber1
    global randomNumber2
    userAnswer = int( input( "What is " + str(randomNumber1) + " + " + \
                str(randomNumber2) + " ?: ") )
    return userAnswer

def checkAnswer (userAnswer):
    global randomNumber1
    global randomNumber2

    correctAnswer = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2
    print()
    if userAnswer == correctAnswer:
        print("Congratulations!")
    else:
        print( "It's wrong. The correct answer is", correctAnswer )

def main():
   userAnswer = askQuestion()
   checkAnswer(userAnswer)

main()
```

Comment: Even if you did add a loop, your answers wouldn't be preserved at all.

Comment: Read about [for loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This script asks 10 questions as specified by the argument for the ask_questions function

```
import random

def ask_questions(n):
    for q in range(n):
        n1 = random.randint(1, 250)
        n2 = random.randint(1, 250)

        user_answer = int(input('\nWhat is {} + {}? '.format(n1, n2)))
        if user_answer == n1 + n2:
            print("Congratulations!")
        else:
            print('It\'s wrong. The correct answer is {}'.format(n1 + n2))

def main():
    ask_questions(10)

main()
```

Comment: But how do I have it repeat for 10 questions. My instructions are " The program should use a loop to display 10 problems and then give a final score."

Comment: Also, How do I add a menu for options in the beginning? for operations + - x ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator, random

ops = {"+": lambda a, b: operator.add(a, b),
       "-": lambda a, b: operator.sub(a, b),
       "*": lambda a, b: operator.mul(a, b)}

def main():
    score = 0
    for q in range(10):
        a, b = random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)
        op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
        ans = ops[op](a, b)

        print(a, op, b, "=", end = " ")
        user_input = int(input())

        if user_input == ans:
            score += 1

    print("Scored:", score)


main()
```

Two random numbers are generated as well as the operator. The program loops 10 times then outputs the final score.

**Output**

```
7 - 6 = 1
9 + 4 = 13
9 + 8 = 17
1 - 1 = 0
9 + 7 = 16
5 + 7 = 12
7 * 8 = 56
8 - 8 = 0
4 + 3 = 7
9 + 6 = 15
Scored: 10
```